# drupal expandable hover menu

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, drupal

Anyone know of a decent way of making drupal menus exapandable when the user hovers over the parent menu item.

Comment: Expandable menus are normally pretty easy, what's the mark-up look like? Are you able to use your own CSS, or do you need it to be a Drupal plug-in?

Comment: Yeah I can set it as expanded but that's then static - I want it to expand when the user hovers... Ideally a nice jquery so it slides down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrote this bit of jquery which did the trick;

```
<style>
    ul.menu li.expanded ul.menu {  display:none;}
    ul.menu li.active-trail ul.menu{ display:block;}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("li.expanded").mouseenter(function(){

        $("li.expanded").each( function() {
            $(this).find("ul.menu").css('display','none');
        }); 

        $(this).find("ul.menu").css('display','block');
        $(this).animate( {'height':'100%'},1500);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish a drop down menus, like at [this](http://esn.org) site, please refer to Drupal's Nice Menus module. It's very easy to use. Documentation and information on this module you can find [here](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus).

Hope this is what you're looking for :)

regards

Answer (score 0):

Some themes come with expandable menus. Any theme based on the fusion ( http://drupal.org/project/fusion ) or adaptive theme ( http://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme ) will give you expandable drop down menus. Check out the links to see which themes are based on the above themes.

To enable a dropdown just make sure that the menu item is market as "expanded".

No need to install any additional module or mess around with the theme code. Easy.

Comment: Yeah I can set it as expanded but that's then static - I want it to expand when the user hovers... Ideally a nice jquery so it slides down?

Comment: That's why you should use something like the aqua marina theme ( http://drupal.org/project/acquia_marina ). Its a fusion based theme ( http://drupal.org/project/fusion ) that supports jQuery slide down menus "out of the box"

Comment: Well the site is built now - so that's not a solution for me, I'm currently writing some jquery to do this and I'll post it once I've done.

Comment: Becuase nobody mentioned that before!